# How to control freeglut's warnings

Tags: freeglut

When freeglut is compiled with `_DEBUG` it outputs a lot of warnings of different types when an event occurs, such as: 'LeaveNotify', 'MotionNotify' and 'ButtonPress'. Some of these are more useful than others depending on the situation. Specifically, 'MotionNotify' basically spams my debug logs as it is generated on mouse motion.

I am looking for a way to control the warning level by disabling warnings by type.

I have looked into `FREEGLUT_PRINT_WARNING` , but this does not work. Warnings are printed either with this defined or undefined. Even if it worked, I am still looking for a finer-grained solution.

I have also looked into `glutInitWarningFunc` to set a callback for warning printing. The callback function receives the formatted string for printing and the corresponding list of arguments. Warnings can be disabled entirely with this, but I see no other option besides string comparison for filtering what should actually get printed. As I see it, comparing strings in at least every mouse movement would be heavy.